# findByIdAndUpdate overwrites existing value

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

facing a small issue that whenever I try to update a 'comments' property it automatically overwrites old property, doesn't add next value to the array. Tried many options like adding $set parameter as option, removing it, adding overwrite: false, but not successfully. Been looking at the docs, but feels like I'm something missing and even docs can't help me.

My Model:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");


const TicketSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        minlength: 5,
        maxlength: 50,
        required: [true, "Please validate title"]
    },
    description: {
        type: String,
        minlength: 10,
        maxlength: 200,
        required: [true, "Please validate description"]
    },
    comments: {
        type: Array,
        default: []
    },
    status: {
        type: String,
        enum: ["in progress", "resolved", "pending"],
        default: "pending",
    },
    priority: {
        type: String,
        enum: ["regular", "medium", "high"],
        default: "regular"
    },
    createdBy: {
        type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "User",
        required: [true, "Please provide user"],
    }
}, {
    timestamps: true,
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Ticket', TicketSchema);
```

My controller:

```
const updateUser = async (req, res) => {
    const {
        body: {username, email, firstname, lastname, country, password, comments},
        params: {
            id: employeeId
        }
    } = req;

    const user = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(employeeId, req.body, {
        $set: {
            comments: req.body.comments
        }
    }, {
        new: true, runValidators: true, upsert: true
    }).select(["-password"]);

    // Don't allow IT users to change credentials for IT and ADM users.
    if (user.type.startsWith("IT") || user.type.startsWith("ADM")) throw new NotFoundError(`No user with id ${employeeId}`);

    if (!user) throw new NotFoundError(`No user with id ${employeeId}`);

    res.status(StatusCodes.OK).json({user});

};
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use [`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) operator instead of `$set`.

Assuming `req.body.comments` is an array with comments, you could use `$each` to construct something like this:

```
const user = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(employeeId, req.body, {
    $push: {
        comments: { $each: req.body.comments }
    }, {
        new: true, runValidators: true, upsert: true
    }
}).select(["-password"]);
```

Comment: Is it possible somehow to keep the logic the same as mine? What I mean firstly I want to pass the whole body and then in options to set $push instead of $set? Or I have to attach whole object to $push?

Comment: You probably will have to use `$each` as well. I updated the answer.

Comment: Not sure where's the problem, but I've tried your method and doesn't work :| Just rewrites old values, doesn't add new to comments array